# Trying to set a cooldown on hide(); for a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, im trying to make my first menu ever, and im getting stucked with this dropdown script.
The logic is simple and classic, hovering a certain `<li>` will drop a submenu, once you mouseleave the `<li>` the dropdown hides (well, it shouldnt really hide, but when u move your mouse on another `<li>`, the submenu must be closed, otherwise i will just have billions of submenus popped and couldnt close anyone)
So, can someone help me?
This is my actual source:

```
    $(function() { 
        $('.menu-content-news').hover(function() { 
        $('.subnav').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    });
        $('.menu-content-news').mouseleave(function () {
        $('.subnav').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
        $('.subnav').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
        $('.subnav').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

});

And this is my website http://nfd.altervista.org/kindmenuonpure.html (obviously still working on it, i made it just for challenge and for test my ability, i really want to improve on this web design field, and this is my first test. If you feel to, also leave a feedback about the site, or how to improve it)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending CSS you can use the jQuery function .hide(); or toggle You can add a parameter to it to set the duration:

```
$('.menu-content-news').hover( function() { 
    $('.subnav').toggle('slow'); 
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mczE9/)

[jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: and thats fine, but the main question was how to avoid that the submenu hides when you are leaving the li.
If you notice, i updated it on my site, but the problemi is still the same, im having troubles cause you cannot effectively go on the submenu, because it hides before you even pass on it.